# Can I change a table from internal to external in hive?

Tags: types, hive, external

I created a table in hive as a managed table, but it was supposed to be external,  is it possible to change the table type of the table without losing the data?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE <table> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE')
```

Note: EXTERNAL and TRUE need to caps or it will not work

Comment: This doesn't move you data to external locations actually, your data are still on HDFS. @Olaf 's solution is right

Comment: As [@Shan Hadoop Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4304732/shan-hadoop-learner) mentions, this only works if the table is non-transactional, which is NOT the default behavior of managed tables. In all likelihood, one will need to recreate the table schema as an EXTERNAL table, specify the location of the data, and then INSERT OVERWRITE with the data.

Comment: I also agree only setting up External will not work, because in general table is considered external because it is storing data at other location rather than dbfs.

Answer (score 3):

```
alter table <table_name> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE')
```

Note: It work only if it is **non transactional internal/managed** table.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your data files from the Hive data location to the location you planned to store your external table, drop the table and re-create it as external.

Comment: figured it out!

ALTER TABLE <table> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');